# Repeating a function and saving the results. R

Tags: r, function

There are some questions similar to this one but I still cannot solve my particular issue. I have a function to obtain random samples of rows from a df. Using dplyr library.

```
rohis <- function(dat, ind, n) {
    ind <- enquo(ind)
    dat %>%
        filter(UQ(ind) %in% sample(unique(UQ(ind)), n)) %>%
        slice(sample(row_number()))
}
```

Now I want to repeat this function 10 times and store the results in a list:

```
lst <- list()
for (i in 1:10){
    i = rohis(data, ind, 3)
    lst[[length(lst) + 1]] = i
}
```

However got this error:

```
Error in lst[[length(lst) + 1]] <- i : 
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Here are some data:

```
data <- structure(list(pos1 = c(5, 15, 25, 40, 80, 5, 18, 22, 38, 84, 
                    5, 16, 50, 92, 31, 50, 20, 30, 50, 70, 27, 50, 60, 50, 90, 20, 
                    40, 54, 65, 78, 7, 17, 27, 42, 85, 10, 19, 25, 39, 88, 10, 19, 
                    55, 93, 32, 54, 22, 35, 52, 72, 29, 55, 65, 55, 95, 22, 46, 57, 
                    67, 79), pos2 = c(10, 17, 30, 42, 90, 10, 20, 24, 42, 87, 10, 
                                      19, 52, 100, 40, 70, 25, 32, 60, 90, 30, 60, 71, 60, 100, 25, 
                                      50, 50, 69, 90, 19, 27, 39, 49, 99, 20, 29, 30, 49, 92, 20, 29, 
                                      59, 100, 48, 76, 30, 39, 67, 98, 36, 68, 76, 65, 100, 30, 55, 
                                      55, 70, 100), chr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                            1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                            1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                            2, 2, 2, 2, 2), ind = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                              3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                              4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                                                                              6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class ="factor")), .Names = c("pos1", "pos2", "chr", "ind"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: generally I would suggest you to use `lapply(rep(3,10),function(x) rohis(data,ind,x))`

Comment: I also think you can't just loop through an empty list. Lists in R are very flexible, but I think objects in R always need some value. When I looped through lists the last time (meaning before I [discovered `lapply`](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family)), I set my list e.g. `lst=list(1:3,1:2)` and called it with `lst[[i]]`

Comment: What is `ind`? It's not defined. Besides, your loop is iterating on `i` and then, in the loop you change its value! You should do `j = rohis(...)`. Also, there's an indentation issue with your `data`, the last part of it is not readable. Could you please remove the blanks from the beginning of the lines?

Comment: Ok now the data is fixed... sorry.

Comment: And so does it work now? I don't get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

If you want to filter for specific `ind`, and then sample random rows you can try this function

```
rohis <- function(dat, I, n) {
    require(dplyr)
    dat %>%
        filter(ind %in% I) %>%
        slice(sample(nrow(.), n))
}
```

To repeat 10 times and save in a list do

```
library(purrr)
ans <- map(1:10, ~rohis(data, "A", 3))
```

To filter on multiple `ind`

```
ans <- map(1:10, ~rohis(data, c("A","E"), 3))
```

**Alternative**

To sample random rows without filtering

```
alt <- function(dat, n) {
    dat %>%
        slice(sample(nrow(.), n))
}

map(1:10, ~alt(data, 3))
```

**Sampling random ind**

```
alt2 <- function(dat, n) {
    I <- sample(unique(dat$ind), n)
    dat %>%
        filter(ind %in% I)
}

map(1:10, ~alt2(data, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help chi Pak... but my intention is not to filter for specific ind, and then sample random rows... My intention is to sample random ind getting all the rows in that ind... Indeed after this step I need to pass a function to all the elements on the list...